# Why does the C Standard allow this code to compile without errors?

Tags: c, language-lawyer

Here is a piece of code that seems to be accepted without errors:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main() {
    if (strcmp(1, 2))
        printf(3);
}
```

Compiling with `clang -std=c11 -Weverything` does produce 4 warnings:

```
badstrcmp.c:5:16: warning: incompatible integer to pointer conversion passing 'int' to parameter of type 'const char *' [-Wint-conversion]
    if (strcmp(1, 2))
               ^
/usr/include/string.h:77:25: note: passing argument to parameter '__s1' here
int      strcmp(const char *__s1, const char *__s2);
                            ^
badstrcmp.c:5:19: warning: incompatible integer to pointer conversion passing 'int' to parameter of type 'const char *' [-Wint-conversion]
    if (strcmp(1, 2))
                  ^
/usr/include/string.h:77:43: note: passing argument to parameter '__s2' here
int      strcmp(const char *__s1, const char *__s2);
                                              ^
badstrcmp.c:6:16: warning: incompatible integer to pointer conversion passing 'int' to parameter of type 'const char *' [-Wint-conversion]
        printf(3);
               ^
/usr/include/stdio.h:259:36: note: passing argument to parameter here
int      printf(const char * __restrict, ...) __printflike(1, 2);
                                       ^
badstrcmp.c:6:16: warning: format string is not a string literal (potentially insecure) [-Wformat-security]
        printf(3);
               ^
badstrcmp.c:6:16: note: treat the string as an argument to avoid this
        printf(3);
               ^
               "%s",
4 warnings generated.
```

My question is **Why does the C Standard allow it to compile?**. This kind of problems should be diagnosed as errors and the code should be refused. Why does the C Standard allow the program to be translated?

Comment: I love clang's sense of humor: *warning: format string is not a string literal (potentially insecure)*

Comment: The compiler does its best - under the illusion that the programmer knows best

Comment: @EdHeal: OK, I rephrased the question: why does the C Standard allow this?  The compiler conforms to the Standard, but accepting this kind of non-sense is counter productive.

Comment: some warnings should be errors. But that would break the compiling of badly written codes which work. This code has no chance to work at all.

Comment: If you write crap - you get crap

Comment: I imagine that if you write code for an embedded system you can pass hardcoded addresses `strcmp(0x345625,0x432252)` and it could mean something.

Comment: In embedded, you must be allowed to use hard coded memory locations. Allowing such stuff is not *weakness* but what C is about: close to the bone.

Comment: C evolved from an untyped, byte-oriented language (https://www.bell-labs.com/usr/dmr/www/chist.html) and aims to be backwards compatible with code that's several decades old. Compiling with `-Wall -Werror` (+possibly some additional flags that weaken that a little) makes this a non-problem.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre: that would be fine if you explicitly cast these integers as `(char*)` or `(void*)`.

Comment: @WeatherVane: explicit casts should be mandatory with `-std=c11`.

Comment: @chqrlie do you mean "are" or "should be"?

Comment: "C Standard?" C standard clearly states that the code is invalid. Everything else is quirks of your compiler.

Comment: @WeatherVane: they obviously aren't, but I think they should be.

Comment: @chqrlie: Explicit casts in this context have always been mandatory in C since the very first standard C89/90. If your compiler accepts this in `-std=c90` mode, it will likely accept it without a cast in `-std=c11` mode as well.

Comment: @Jean-François Fabre: That could mean something, but C language says that if you really want to do it, you have to do it as `strcmp((const char *) 0x345625, (cost char *) 0x432252)` (feel free to omit `const`). It is not much more typing, yet meets the requirements of the language and clearly conveys the programmer's intent.

Comment: "I think they should be" - that's a topic for a blog post, not a SO question.

Comment: My question was *Why does the C Standard not specify that programs containing constraint violations should not translate successfully?*

It does not because the Committee did not think it should.

The only case where it specifically excludes successful translation is if the programs contains an active `#error` directive.  Beyond this special case, the Standard does not have a conceptual difference between warnings and errors. It is up to the compiler implementors to chose which kind of problem cause failure to translate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main() {
    if (strcmp(1, 2))
        printf(3);
}
```

The calls to `strcmp` and `printf`, since they pass arguments of incorrect types (and there is no implicit conversion available), are *constraint violations*.

The C standard requires at least one diagnostic message for any program that violates a constraint or syntax rule. A warning is a perfectly valid diagnostic message as far as the standard is concerned.

Here's what the standard says (quoting the [N1570](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf) draft of the C11 standard, section 5.1.1.3):

> A conforming implementation shall produce at least one diagnostic
>   message (identified in an implementation-defined manner) if a
>   preprocessing translation unit or translation unit contains a
>   violation of any syntax rule or constraint, even if the behavior is
>   also explicitly specified as undefined or implementation-defined.
>   Diagnostic messages need not be produced in other circumstances.

The only case where the standard actually requires a source file to be *rejected* is when it contains a `#error` directive. Section 4, paragraph 4:

> The implementation shall not successfully translate a preprocessing
>   translation unit containing a **`#error`** preprocessing directive unless it
>   is part of a group skipped by conditional inclusion.

I personally would prefer gcc and clang to reject programs that violate syntax rules or constraints, but as I said non-fatal warnings are permitted by the standard. If you want such programs to be rejected, there are various options you can use, such as `-std=c11 -pedantic-errors`. Note that gcc and clang do not fully conform to the C standard by default, but these non-fatal warnings are not an example of that non-conformance.

Answer (score 6):

Your question seems to be based on an invalid premise that C Standard somehow "allows this code to compile". In reality C Standard does not have such concept as "allowing or not allowing the code to compile".

If the code is invalid, the Standard requires compilers to tell you about that through diagnostic messages. The Standard does not require compilers to refuse to compile your code. They can still go ahead and compile it in some implementation-defined way.

Your code is blatantly invalid according to C Standard. Standard C language does not allow *implicit* integer to pointer conversions. And your compiler clearly told you about that through diagnostic messages. This is enough for the compiler to meet the Standard's requirements.

After that all bets are off. Your compiler might compile it into "something", but this is not a conforming C program. Its behavior is not defined by the language.

As for the format of diagnostic messages you receive (and whether they are "warnings" or "errors") - it is a question to your compiler. In C it is a *Quality of Implementation* issue. C Standard has nothing to do with it.

You can ask `clang` to report C language constraint violations as "errors" by supplying a `-pedantic-errors` flag. It is not perfect for that purpose, but it will make compiler to refuse compiling your code (if that's what you want).

Comment: *C Standard does not have such concept as "allowing or not allowing the code to compile"*: actually, it does, but only for a very specific case: ***4. Conformance** 4.The implementation shall not successfully translate a preprocessing translation unit containing a #error preprocessing directive unless it is part of a group skipped by conditional inclusion.*

Answer (score 5):

> and the code should be refused.

Well that's a big assumption.

To actually quote the standard:

> an implementation is free to produce any number of diagnostics as long as a valid program is still correctly translated. It may also successfully translate an invalid program.

([5.1.1.3 note 9](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf#page=30))

The standard does not place significant limitations on what a compiler has to do when an error is encountered, precisely for the reason that in many situations and on many platforms, "errors" may actually be well-defined (by the implementation) extension behaviours. It may also be better, from the perspective of providing useful information to the developer, to continue translating and pick up other errors or information in the following part of the program, than to give up at the first incredibly minor, still-syntactically-valid difficult point.

It also prefers not to make too many assumptions about what exactly "translation" involves (translation phase 7 is basically just "something happens here"). There are no notions of "machine code" (excluding extensions like [J.5.7](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf#page=598)) in the strictly standard version of the language, for instance, so the standard cannot prohibit a compiler from emitting it.

Answer (score 4):

On the one hand, the standard explicitly allows integer to pointer type conversions (cf. [C99 standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1124.pdf)):

> 6.3.2.3 Pointers
>   ...
>   (5) An integer may be converted to any pointer type. Except as previously
>   specified, the result is implementation-defined, might not be
>   correctly aligned, might not point to an entity of the referenced
>   type, and might be a trap representation.56)

On the other hand, the standard requires an explicit cast in such situations:

> 6.5.4 Cast operators... (3) Conversions that involve pointers, other than where permitted by the constraints of 6.5.16.1, shall be specified by means of an explicit cast

So `printf(3)` is clearly not correct, but whether it yields an error or a warning seems to be - in this case - subject to the compiler.

Comment: Absolutely not true. Your quote simply says that language *supports* integer to pointer conversions in proper contexts (e.g. through an **explicit** cast), but standard *explicitly prohibits* **implicit** integer to pointer conversions. 6.5.4/3 "Conversions that involve pointers, other than where permitted by the constraints of 6.5.16.1, shall be specified by means of an explicit cast."

Comment: @AnT: Good point. I wonder why 6.3.2.3(5) does not refer to this section, at least in a footnote (there are footnotes, but just regarding address space). And the compilers I tried actually accept it without explicit cast. Any idea?

Comment: Actually, at the very beginning of 6.3 it says "This
subclause specifies the result required from such an implicit conversion, as well as those that result from a cast operation (an explicit conversion)." The purpose of that sentence is to emphasize the fact that 6.3 about the *result* of conversion. 6.3 is not intended to somehow allow these conversions to happen implicitly.

Comment: Then it says, "The list in 6.3.1.8 summarizes the conversions performed by most ordinary operators; it is supplemented as required by the discussion of each operator in 6.5." I.e. you are supposed to read the description of each individual operator to see what it can/cannot do implicitly.

Answer (score 3):

If you want not to compile such code then use `-Werror` as additional flag which turns each warning to compiling error and your code would not be compiled.

Comment: Of course, I use `-Werror` along with a carefully tailored list of `-Wno-xxx`... but what is the use for not diagnosing these as errors?  Are people on the Committee trying to keep the language a mine field for newbies?

Comment: @chqrlie C is a minefield and so is assembler, whence it originated to make programmer's lives easier.

Comment: Not `-Werror`, but `-pedantic-errors`.